# ORA-00904 invalid identifier - but that exists

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, ora-00904

I have a strange Oracle problem with an identifier which works in another subquery of the same query and is defined in the FROM part of the main select. The `select coalesce(typ...)` returns exactly one row and field. This is the working version of the query:

```
SELECT
  v.id AS vid, 
  p.name AS pname, 
  v.name,
  TO_CHAR(a.uploaddate,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AS scandate,

  (SELECT COALESCE(sum(issuecount),0) 
   FROM foldercountcache fc, folder f 
   WHERE fc.folder_id = f.id 
    AND fc.projectversion_id = v.id AND f.name like '1 -%'
  ) as crit,

  (SELECT COALESCE(typ,'No Issues') FROM
   (SELECT ROWNUM AS r,cri,typ,n FROM
    (SELECT f.name AS cri,i.issuetype AS typ, count(i.issuetype) as n
     FROM issue i 
     LEFT JOIN folder f ON i.projectversion_id = f.projectversion_id AND i.folder_id = f.id 
     WHERE (i.projectversion_id = 15284846 AND f.name like '1%') 
     GROUP BY f.name,i.issuetype 
     ORDER BY cri, n DESC
    ) 
   ) WHERE r=2
  ) AS top2

FROM projectversion v INNER JOIN project p ON p.id = v.project_id 
 INNER JOIN artifact a ON a.projectversion_id = v.id
WHERE a.uploaddate = 
 (SELECT max(uploaddate) 
  FROM artifact 
  WHERE projectversion_id = v.id AND status = 'PROCESS_COMPLETE'
 )
ORDER BY p.name, v.name, a.uploaddate ;
```

I need to replace the number `15284846` with `v.id`. However, doing this I receive the
`ORA-00904 "V"."ID" invalid identifier` 
error from Oracle.
Please note, that the `v.id` is used without problem in the first subselect which begins with `select COALESCE`

What is wrong here?

Comment: It's because you're trying to correlate the parent v.id in a grandchild subquery - you can only do this with child subqueries. See https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1853075500346799932

Comment: Just for completeness, Oracle 12c supports more than one level.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This helps a little bit forward. Now I only need to find a way to transform the query so that v.id goes from grandchild level to child level.